# Older version still downloadable even after uploading newer version of apk in Google Play

Tags: android

I have updated new version of apk on Google Play. But still in statistics I see people downloading older version, how is that possible ? Has anyone encountered this problem ?

Regards

Comment: How long since the update? It can take a few hours to be visible on the Google Play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. This is because mobile app stores cache. If you go to GOOGLE APP -> My Apps -> ALL and install from that cache it will also download and install the apk which u unpublished long back in past. Big bug in Google....PHEWWWWWWWWWW...

Answer (score 2):

Are the new APK's requirements the same as the old one? It can come from there.

For example, let's say the old APK's `minSdkVersion` is 8, and the new one is 9. Then users with SDK version 8 will still be able to download the old APK.

Comment: minipif : Thanks, but i didn't get what user has to do with "minSdkVersion" because once you increment integer of "appVersion" the end user should not be able to download older version itself. Because when we update apk it actually replaces older apk, so old apk is no more in Google Play. Explain me if my understanding is wrong

Answer (score 1):

As minipif has said, you may have changed minSdkVersion in your manifest, or some other attribute e.g. supports-screens.

If this results in you decreasing the number of devices supported in your new apk then, by default, Google Play will keep hold of the old apk and deliver it to devices not supported by the new apk (but supported by the old apk).

You can override this by simply unpublishing your old apk in the developer console.

Comment: Sheldon : Thanks for your kind reply. But there is only one entry in my list which says "published" and which is the only entry where i upgrade apk. To unpublish any older apk, i should at-least see older application in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you replaced that with older apk by switching to new apk update?

If yes, it takes couple of hours to update in android market.

Answer (score 0):

Play Store app has cache. You can delete cache from settings.

Comment: mromer : You mean to say cache in my mobile google app. Can u give a brief of it ?

Comment: The cache of users´ device. But a month is long time to keep cache. Sorry.

Comment: Guys, I got it. This is because mobile app stores cache. If you go to GOOGLE APP -> My Apps -> ALL and install from that cache it will also download and install the apk which u unpublished long back in past. Big bug in Google....PHEWWWWWWWWWW...